# Generators vs Callbacks for Long Operations?

Tags: python, asynchronous

It seems for the most part people suggest generators for threadless async operations. In [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805958/python-asynchronous-callbacks-and-generators) the top answer claims that callbacks are ugly (but workable).

I have a web-scraper that will return data from a list of weblinks. For each link I'd like it to either yield or callback with the processed data for that specific link. Each operation requires a few HTTP calls and on a slow network may take hundreds or thousands of milliseconds to complete. I'm wondering what is best practice for when the operation itself takes a long (possibly indefinite) amount of time to complete.

Comment: You're really talking about coroutines, not generators, in this context. And I would say this is an opinion-based question. [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), which is built around callbacks, is quite popular. Python 3.4 introduces the [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/asyncio.html) module, which can be used with callbacks, but also supports coroutines. [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) can also support both, but favors coroutines. It's quite possible any of those three (or any other asynchronous framework) would suit your needs just fine.

Comment: Also, some interesting reading on this topic, from the author of Twisted: https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2012/01/concurrency-spectrum-from-callbacks-to.html.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a "best practice" here. This is concurrency control and can be done with Actor Model, Coroutines, Event-Driven, etc. (*This is a good question in general though -- Just IHMO -- Opinionated*).